# Getting TypeError: <file object at ..>is not json serializable

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to fetch json data from url link of api. i want to write data into a json file locally. but i am getting this error

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <addinfourl at 52466872 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x0320C330>> is not JSON serializable
```

my code is give bellow

```
import json
import urllib2
urllink=urllib2.urlopen("url")



with open('urljson.json','w')as outfile:
    json.dumps(urllink,outfile,indent=4,sort_keys=True, separators=(',', ':'))
```

kindly help me, Thanks in advance
Kalyan

Comment: You want `dump` not `dumps` and you likely want to read the stuff from the url first. I'm confused about what you want... if you are reading a json string from "url" it doesn't need to be json dumped again.... just write what you read.

Comment: thanks for reply i have added this code for reading
data=json.loads(urllink.read())
print data
but error  message is showing ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: `urllink` is a file-like object and you must *read* the content from it. it is not itself the content. also, as tdelaney notes, you don't need to re-seralize it because it's already JSON.

Comment: So, what's being read? You could write it to a file and check.

Comment: oh thanks i did i have just added  urllib2.urlopen(url).read and print the url
it worked  :). though it is not the question topic but it will be fine for me if i could format json data removing additional spaces and nextline character :p